# Split text and handle timer to change style of Text in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am stuck. I have a string:

```
"Fa Fo Fi Fe Fy Fu Fą Fę\n af of if ef yf uf\n\nÓm Ót Ód Ól Ók Ós Ór Óp Óc Ón\n Ów Óg Ół Óz Ój\n mó tó dó ló kó só ró pó bó có nó\nwó gó łó zó jó"
```

and I want to look like:

```
Fa Fo Fi Fe Fy Fu Fą Fę
af of if ef yf uf

Óm Ót Ód Ól Ók Ós Ór Óp Óc Ón
mó tó dó ló kó só ró pó bó có nó
```

This part I have done in:

```
_renderItem(context, Level4Item item) {
  cardKeys.putIfAbsent(item.id, () => GlobalKey<FlipCardState>());
  cardKey = cardKeys[item.id]!;
  List<String> stringList = item.text.split("\n");

  stringList.forEach((e) => print(e));

  return Container(
    height: double.maxFinite,
    child: ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: stringList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, i) => Text.rich(
        TextSpan(
          text: stringList[i],
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 42,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Now I want to add Timer to change color of every part after 2 seconds. For example: after run application only word: `"Fa"` should be red, after 2 seconds only word: `"Fo"` should be red, after next 2 seconds only word: `"Fi"` should be red etc until word `"nó"`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add two parts:

First part is to split one more time using the space character in order to have a text span for each word and not just entire line.

Add an index for `currentlyHighlightedIndex` that will be incremented by the timer.

Then you associate a style either default or red if the `currentIndex == currentlyHighlightedIndex`.

Now second part is to set the timer, which is a simple Timer.periodic :

```
int currentlyHighlightedIndex = 0;

@override
 void initState() {
    _timer = new Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 2), (timer) {
    currentlyHighlightedIndex++;
  });
  super.initState();
}

@override
 void dispose() {
   _timer.cancel();
   super.dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String text =
          "Fa Fo Fi Fe Fy Fu Fą Fę\n af of if ef yf uf\n\nÓm Ót Ód Ól Ók Ós Ór Óp Óc Ón\n Ów Óg Ół Óz Ój\n mó tó dó ló kó só ró pó bó có nó\nwó gó łó zó jó";
  
  int active = 0;

  List<String> lines = [], words = [];
  
  late Timer timer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    lines = text.split('\n');
    words = text.replaceAll('\n','').split(" ");
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds:2),(t){
      if(active < words.length-1){
        active++;
        setState((){});
      }else{
        timer.cancel();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor : Colors.white,
     body: Center(
       child: Column(
         mainAxisSize : MainAxisSize.min,
         children : lines
                      .map<Widget>((s) => 
                                   Row(
                        children : s.split(' ')
                      .map<Widget>((s) => Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(s,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: s == words[active] ? Colors.red : Colors.black)),
                      ))
                      .toList()))
                      .toList()),
       ),
    );
  }
  
  @override
  void dispose(){
    timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```